How to implement DataTables buttons in Falcon (Bootstrap theme)?
What I am trying to do
I have a html table where I would like to hide and expand certain columns using DataTables in a Bootstrap theme called Falcon.
Languages used
I am using PHP (version 7.2.24) and HTML - no module builders and no frameworks (besides Bootstrap).
Inspiration & Documentation
I have found the following example from DataTables own documentation: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/columnGroups.html
This is the documentation from Falcon and how they use DataTables:
https://prium.github.io/falcon/v3.20.0/modules/components/jquery-components.html
Sadly they do not use DataTables buttons in their examples.
Code that works
I have the following code that works to create a table using DataTables (without buttons)
$tableOptions = [
        "paging" => false,
        "searching" => false,
        "scrollCollapse" => false,
        "scrollX" => false,
        "language" => [
            "info" => "",
            "infoEmpty" => "No results",
            "infoFiltered" => "(filtreret from _MAX_ rows)",
            "lengthMenu" => "Show _MENU_ rows per page",
            "zeroRecords" => "Nothing found - sorry",
            "search" => "Search: _INPUT_",
            "paginate" => [
                "previous" => "Previous",
                "next" => "Next"
            ]
        ]
    ]

<table class="table mb-0 data-table fs-10" data-datatables='<?php echo $tableOptions; ?>'>
    <thead class="bg-200">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-900 sort text-wrap"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
            <td class="text-wrap"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

Code that doesn't work
I assumed that the following would show the DataTables buttons:
collapseTableOptions = [
        "paging" => true,
        "searching" => true,
        "scrollCollapse" => false,
        "scrollX" => true,
        "scrollY" => 450,
        "pageLength" => 10,
        "lengthMenu" => [[10, 15, -1], ["10", "15", "All"]],
        "language" => [
            "info" => "",
            "infoEmpty" => "No results",
            "infoFiltered" => "(filtreret from _MAX_ rows)",
            "lengthMenu" => "Show _MENU_ rows per page",
            "zeroRecords" => "Nothing found - sorry",
            "search" => "Search: _INPUT_",
            "paginate" => [
                "previous" => "Previous",
                "next" => "Next"
            ]
        ],
        "layout" => [
            "topStart" => [
                "buttons" => [
                    [
                        "extend" => "colvisGroup",
                        "text" => "Basic info",
                        "show" => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                        "hide" => [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
                    ],
                    [
                        "extend" => "colvisGroup",
                        "text" => "Show all",
                        "show" => ":hidden"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

but no buttons was displayed.
These are the scripts I have included relevant to DataTables:
<script src="Falcon_Bootstrap/vendors/datatables.net/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="Falcon_Bootstrap/vendors/datatables.net-bs5/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="Datatables/buttons/3.0.2/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
<script src="Datatables/buttons/3.0.2/buttons.bootstrap5.js"></script>
<script src="Datatables/buttons/3.0.2/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>


Suggestion: Start with a DataTables set-up which uses Bootstrap 5, and Buttons (including ColVis) - but which does not use Falcon. You can build that using the official DataTables downloads page. Then see if you can add Falcon to that working demo. Unfortunately, it looks like Falcon is not freely available, so that makes it harder for us to do this ourselves.
